# Can I upgrade RAM to 8GB in a Sony VGN Z620D notebook?

Tags: laptop, memory, sony-vaio

The marketing specs say 4GB max but the marketing specs also indicate Windows Vista 32bit (or Win XP) which might be the limiting factor.  Can I upgrade (or at least safely attempt without damage to laptop or new RAM)?

I was planning a new O/S install to overcome memory limitations on that end, then install 8GB instead of the 4GB max.  Ideally, I'd hope to hear from someone who has a Vaio and has done this.

If personal experience is not available, then I was hoping for an authoritative source on the safety of using more RAM than 'allowed'.

I've read lots of opinions on the internet (including here) but nothing that made me feel confident, including the other answers.  I realize the answer might be, "you'll never know until you try" but I was hoping someone else had tried first.  If no one has done this and can tell me, then that probably gives me my best answer even though, "it might work".

Comment: read this http://superuser.com/questions/785236/maximum-ram-restrictions/912319#912319

Comment: Also see: [I want to install more than the supported amount of RAM on my PC. Is it likely to work?](http://superuser.com/questions/73730/i-want-to-install-more-than-the-supported-amount-of-ram-on-my-pc-is-it-likely-t)

Answer (score 0):

According to [Intel, the chipset (Intel GM45) of your laptop](http://ark.intel.com/products/35134/Intel-82GM45-Graphics-and-Memory-Controller-Hub) supports up to 8GB RAM.

```
Max Memory Size (dependent on memory type)  8 GB
```

So you can try to insert 2 * 4GB modules and install a 64Bit Windows.

Answer (score 0):

If your chipset allows 8GB RAM, and you have a 32bit Windows, you will see only the part of RAM that OS can handle (usually 3.5-4GB).

If you want to use the the OS-inaccessible RAM you may still create a ramdisk there (and e.g. put a pagefile on it). I used "Gavotte ramdisk" for that.